# Nhibernate: QuerySyntaxException: 'Class' is not mapped

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<long> _myList = new List<long>();

    public virtual string MyID { get; set; }

    public virtual string MyData
    {
        get
        {
            return SomeStaticClass.Serialize(_myList);
        }
        set
        {
            _myList = SomeStaticClass.Deserialize<List<long>>(value);
        }
    }

    public virtual List<long> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
    }
}
```

And the following mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="MyNamespace"
               namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="MyNamespace.MyClass" table="MY_TABLE">
    <id name="MyID" column="MY_ID" type="System.String">
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="MyData" column="MY_DATA"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to run the following line:

```
session.Delete("From MyClass m");
```

I am getting a QuerySyntaxException with the message "MyClass is not mapped [From MyClass s]".

When I change the name of the "MyID" field to "ID" in the mapping file, the exception becomes

NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 'ID' in class 'MyNamespace.MyClass'.

so I am assuming it can find the mapping file. I made sure that the mapping file is an embedded resource, checked and dobule checked the namespace and class names in the mapping file. What may cause the error? I think it may relate to the MyList property which is not mapped but I am not sure since I am using non-mapped properties on my other classes without a problem.

**EDIT:** I tried overriding this class, with a class which has no "MyData" property and redefining "MyList" property as string. I am still receiving the same error for my overridden class.

**EDIT 2:** Tried with a very simple class with the same property names with same return types and only simple get; set; blocks. I still get the same error. I am almost sure that nhibernate can see my mapping files because if I change the name of a single property, it gives me PropertyNotFound instead of "class in not mapped".

Comment: Maybe not very helpful but did you verify that your property name is the same as the one in the mapping file? Note that property names are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, I checked all of them a dozen times, after that I copy pasted them again and checked again a dozen times.

Comment: When I received an error similiar to this I found that [this](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/Nhibernate-QuerySyntaxException-is-not-mapped-from.aspx) was the cause. I have written many articles about NHibernate [here](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/archiveList.aspx?TAG=NHibernate). I hope this one resolves the problem and the other articles help.

Comment: @SerhatÖzgel Were you able to resolve this issue?  I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 8):

How are you loading the hbms?  If they are resources, make sure you've actually set the files to be embedded resources in Visual Studio

Comment: I am sure they are correctly set to embedded resources and I already mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 7):

In case of mapping

```
<class name="MyClass" table="MY_TABLE">
```

you should use, for example:

```
session.CreateQuery("from MyClass")
```

but not:

```
session.CreateQuery("from MY_TABLE")
```

Answer (score 5):

what about if you use

```
session.Delete("From MyNamespace.MyClass m");
```

I was just looking at the [HQL](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html) reference and noticed in their cat example they use fully qualified objects, i.e. Eg.Cat.

Comment: This solved a similar problem too. When I set auto-import to false on my hbm.xml classes, I had to explicitly specify the namespace in the delete function

Comment: NH 4.0 has the same behavior. I had to pass the full name of the target class, even though that class name is unique across the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You should set the related *.hbm.xml as Embedded Resource.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your "Build Action of the file" is "Embedded Resource".

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I forgot to put hbm in the name of mapping XML files.

Answer (score 0):

it seems a bit strange you are specifying the namespace twice in the mapping file. I would try just specifying the name attribute as just "MyClass" instead of "MyNamespace.MyClass" so it would be

```
<class name="MyClass" table="MY_TABLE">
```

Comment: I do not know if your or mine is better but I always map like this and I had no problems until today. Also tried your suggestion but problem still continues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like this. Basically, I included a new project into the solution and I did not map the namespace in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.